# Null value size in Sybase Iq Database

Tags: sql, database, sybase, diskspace, sap-iq

I want to know how much size in large scale the NULL values uses in the Sybase.

In my case i have a lot of BIG tables and i dont know if columns with a lot of NULL values uses or not considerable disk size.

Answer (score 1):

IQ uses tokenization as one of it's compression methods, so duplicate values are stored as a single token.  This means the more duplication you have (NULL or otherwise), the greater level of compression you will see in your database.  So in this case, you should not see a large amount of disk utilization due to the NULL values.

[Compression in SAP/Sybase IQ](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBIQ/SAP+IQ+data+compression+ratio)